# How can I slice this dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe 'data' that looks like this:

```
<bound method NDFrame.head of                 Close                      ...   Volume                    
                    A     AA         TSLA  ...        A        AA      TSLA
Date                                       ...                             
2020-06-24  86.378616  11.14   960.849976  ...  1806600   7562700  10959600
2020-06-25  87.077148  11.83   985.979980  ...  1350100   6728600   9254500
2020-06-26  85.720001  10.93   959.739990  ...  2225800  25817600   8854900
2020-06-29  87.290001  10.99  1009.349976  ...  1302500   7397600   9026400
2020-06-30  88.370003  11.24  1079.810059  ...  1920200   5796600  16881600

[5 rows x 15 columns]>
```

Now, from this dataframe, I would like to get all the data for 'A' into a single dataframe.

I can do this via:

```
df2['Open'] = data['Open']['A']
df2['High'] = data['High']['A']
df2['Low'] = data['Low']['A']
etc.
```

And that works fine... However, there must be a smarter way to do this, right?

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for selecting in `MultiIndex`:

```
df2 = data.xs('A', axis=1, level=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! That was quick! And works great. 

In fact this was so fast, I need to wait another 11 minutes to accept the answer... LoL